# What does 'u' mean in a list?

Tags: python, string, unicode

This is the first time I've came across this. Just printed a list and each element seems to have a `u` in front of it i.e.

```
[u'hello', u'hi', u'hey']
```

**What does it mean and why would a list have this in front of each element?**

As I don't know how common this is, if you'd like to see how I came across it, I'll happily edit the post.

Comment: When you looked up the syntax for string constants, what did you see there?  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange

Answer (score 47, accepted):

it's an indication of unicode string. similar to `r''` for raw string.

```
>>> type(u'abc')
<type 'unicode'>
>>> r'ab\c'
'ab\\c'
```

Comment: Ah, I thought r'' meant something to do with a regular expression?

Comment: It's generally used for regular expressions so we can write things like `r'/[ \t]+/'` instead of `'/[ \\t]+/'` (note the double backslash - you don't have to escape things in raw strings unless you're escaping the closing quote).

Comment: it's often used in regex to avoid all the escaping backslashes

Comment: I see. If I iterate through a unicode listing and check if some string is 'in' the list, will that recognise the string? I'm currently checking each element to see if it matches a certain string and it keeps escaping everytime. Is this because it's Unicode?

Comment: r and u are a bit different. u indicates the type of the string, whereas r (or ru, if you want to use raw unicode literals) makes a normal str (or unicode, if u and r are both used) but that is parsed differently at compile time. 
`>>> repr(r'foo') 
"'foo'" 
>>> repr(u'foo') 
"u'foo'"`
Notice how the r goes away (that's just a matter of what backslashes do) and the u does not (because it makes an object of different type.)

Comment: if your string is a unicode string that uses only ascii characters (as in your example) `in` operation would cast the strings implicitly and you'll get `True`: 'abc' in [u'abc'] results in `True`. If your unicode string uses characters outside of ascii charset, you naturally would get `False` in such test.

Answer (score 11):

[Unicode.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings)

Comment: This link is no longer valid as the page it links to no longer makes any mention of Unicode or `u'`

Answer (score 9):

The `u` just means that the following string is a unicode string (as opposed to a plain ascii string). It has nothing to do with the list that happens to contain the (unicode) strings.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the u' prefix creates a unicode string instead of regular ascii