# How to convert a list of unicode strings to regular strings

Tags: python

I want to remove 'u' from every element in the list, can anybody help me?

```
 [u'four', u'gag', u'prefix', u'woods']
```

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709110/what-does-u-mean-in-a-list) helpful

Comment: The `u` just says that they are unicode strings. They behave like regular strings for the most part

Comment: is there any method through which i can remove them.

Comment: Do you have any good reason to care about that `u`?

Comment: u'Hello, World!' == 'Hello, World!', and same for the four examples in your list.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the encoding of strings.
Do this :

```
l = [u'four', u'gag', u'prefix', u'woods']
l2 = [i.encode('UTF-8') for i in l]

print l2
['four', 'gag', 'prefix', 'woods']
```

Answer (score 1):

The u is an attribute that tells what type of string it is. If it was a byte string, this would be b. If you call type on these, they will return String. The difference between Unicode and something like ASCII is that Unicode is a super-set of ASCII that is the same for 0-127, but has more capability to represent different types of characters. These can be UTF-8 or UTF-32 or whatever, but generally are larger than one byte.

It should behave the same for 99% of the things that you want to do, but you can also change the encoding if you have a function that needs a very particular type of string.