# Scrape text from svg using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am a beginner in python and I'm trying to scrape the actual annual spending price using BeautifulSoup. I'm having a hard time finding what I'm supposed to use in order to extract the text from the svg.

My code I've written so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://abacus.realendpoints.com/ConsoleTemplate.aspx?act=qlrd&req=nav&mop=abacus!main&pk=ed5a81ad-9367-41c8-aa6b-18a08199ddcf&ab-eff=1000&ab-tox=0.1&ab-nov=1&ab-rare=1&ab-pop=1&ab-dev=1&ab-prog=1.0&ab-need=1&ab-time=1543102810'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Monthly figures:**

With selenium you can grab the monthly info by moving to each line

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'http://abacus.realendpoints.com/ConsoleTemplate.aspx?act=qlrd&req=nav&mop=abacus!main&pk=ed5a81ad-9367-41c8-aa6b-18a08199ddcf&ab-eff=1000&ab-tox=0.1&ab-nov=1&ab-rare=1&ab-pop=1&ab-dev=1&ab-prog=1.0&ab-need=1&ab-time=1543102810'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
actions = ActionChains(d)
d.get(url)
paths = WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".highcharts-plot-lines-0 path")))
results = []
for path in paths:
    actions.move_to_element(path).perform()
    actions.click_and_hold(path).perform()
    items = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('#priceChart path + text tspan')
    result = [item.text for item in items]
    if result:
        results.append(result)

print(results)
```

---

[image]

---

**For annual figures:**

Kinda ugly but you can regex out the info from one of the script tags. This is for the annual, not monthly, figures.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import locale

res = requests.get('http://abacus.realendpoints.com/ConsoleTemplate.aspx?act=qlrd&req=nav&mop=abacus!main&pk=ed5a81ad-9367-41c8-aa6b-18a08199ddcf&ab-eff=1000&ab-tox=0.1&ab-nov=1&ab-rare=1&ab-pop=1&ab-dev=1&ab-prog=1.0&ab-need=1&ab-time=1543102810')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
script = soup.select('script')[19]
items = str(script).split('series:')
item = items[2].split('exporting')[0][:-15]
p1 = re.compile('name:(.*)]')
p2 = re.compile('(\d+\.\d+)+')
it = re.finditer(p1, item)
names = [match.group(1).split(',')[0].strip().replace("'",'') for match in it]
it2 = re.finditer(p2, item)
allNumbers = [float(match.group(1)) for match in it2]
actualAnnuals = allNumbers[0::2]
abacusAnnuals = allNumbers[1::2]
actuals = list(zip(names,actualAnnuals))
abacus = list(zip(names,abacusAnnuals))

#Examples:
print(actuals,abacus)

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'English')
print(locale.format('%.2f',sum(actualAnnuals) , True))
```

---

With selenium you can easily grab the headline annual figure with css type selector

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('http://abacus.realendpoints.com/ConsoleTemplate.aspx?act=qlrd&req=nav&mop=abacus!main&pk=ed5a81ad-9367-41c8-aa6b-18a08199ddcf&ab-eff=1000&ab-tox=0.1&ab-nov=1&ab-rare=1&ab-pop=1&ab-dev=1&ab-prog=1.0&ab-need=1&ab-time=1543102810')
print(d.find_element_by_css_selector('tspan').text)
```

annual abacus, price sheet and scenario:

```
print(d.find_elements_by_css_selector('tspan')[3].text, d.find_element_by_css_selector('#Options_price_sheet_id [selected]').text, d.find_element_by_css_selector('#Options_scenario_id [selected]').text )
```

Comment: Yea it works. Thank you. For the annual figure. How would i extract the abacus annual amount?

Comment: Also I would like to scrape the "Price Sheet" and the "Scenario"

Comment: print(d.find_elements_by_css_selector('tspan')[3].text, d.find_element_by_css_selector('#Options_price_sheet_id [selected]').text, d.find_element_by_css_selector('#Options_scenario_id [selected]').text )

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you instead of the total for the annual figures I wanted it for the individual drugs when you hover over the graph. How would that be done?

Comment: Also oddly i get [[u'Pomalyst', u'pomalidomide', u'(multiple myeloma)', u'Actual: $14,165', u'Abacus: $1,000']] as my output for the monthly figures when I use selenium

Comment: I'm not sure where I get the "u" from I get [[u'Farydak', u'panobinostat', u'(multiple myeloma)', u'Actual: $10,625', u'Abacus: $727'], [u'Pomalyst', u'pomalidomide', u'(multiple myeloma)', u'Actual: $14,165', u'Abacus: $1,000'], [u'Velcade', u'bortezomib', u'(multiple myeloma)', u'Actual: $4,474', u'Abacus: $858']]

Comment: I don't get that but do you have a different language setting and perhaps that is the cause? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709110/what-does-u-mean-in-a-list

Comment: I think you are correct. How would code the part where I want to get a annual figures for each individual drug by hovering over the chart on the top?

Comment: Sorry but could I get some help. I've been trying to do this but it does not seem to work @QHarr

Comment: hiya - I am out of the country until the 3rd Feb - can it wait until then?

Comment: im tiny bit in a rush of completing this. Maybe if you could just give me some pointers that would be great. If not that is fine too. I do not want to be disturbing you.

Comment: The values you want are contained in a json string inside one of the script tags on the page. Not sure if also present in a requests based response - you will need to inspect the response text, but definitely present in a rendered page. Loop searching for a script tag containing a substring you know is in the element text then extract that tag and grab the json then use json library to parse. https://ufile.io/0bhza

Comment: Second screen shot of the same tag but showing where the info you want is: https://ufile.io/rp9jz   The first image shows the start of the tag.

Comment: I'm still confused on how to work this. When you have the time is it possible that you show me how to do it?

Comment: No i do not. Could you show me once you get back? Also are you not able to do this with Selenium?

Comment: Sorry for the annooyance but could you show me how its done by any chance?

Comment: Looks like you can use the exact same logic. Please check if this is what you wanted: https://pastebin.com/AcbMCJrR